# Chrome only working for 1 account but not working for other 3 account

Tags: google-chrome

I have logged in my chrome with four accounts and and created all four shortcuts for them but only my one account is working good, all other three are not working and keep saying "Can't connect with the Internet." I have tried deleting persons in the chrome and adding them again but no other person works except the one with I logged in for the first time.

Please help me with this!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try reinstalling Chrome and clearing all cookies (use CCleaner for it)

Comment: Thanks, Reinstalling did the job but i don't know why this wierd thing happened.